# When will spm_jobman run jobs in parallel?

Tags: matlab, matlab-spm, matlabbatch

I'm using `spm_jobman()` run a large number of SPM jobs. I have a machine with a large number of processors, so I would like to be able to run them in parallel. Can `spm_jobman()` run jobs in parallel? If so, how can this be done?